# Static image management module

Tags: 7, media

I want to display a couple of static images on my Drupal 7 site. I could store them in a specific directory I could create in my theme directory (for example).

However, I was wondering whether there was a module to load such images and let Drupal deal with these. I know it is possible to create image fields, but this is (IMHO) overkill compared to a specific directory solution.

Does such module exist? I can't find any.

Comment: I'm going to advise you to stick with image fields. You asked for a module for loading images and for letting Drupal deal with these. I don't know what you really mean when you say "deal with these", but I assume that you like to have some interface for managing your pictures. How many pictures would you like to manage? If it's on the "more then 10" scale, adding some extra information to each picture might be necessary for you to each picture might be necessary for you and for the visitor of your site.

Comment: I get your point about long term issues. In fact, I am already using image fields for some of my content types. However, in this case, it is really a couple of static images and it won't grow in size. For the time being, I have put them in a separate folder next to my theme.

Comment: I am assuming the module I am looking for does not exist. I'll keep this question open a little longer. If nothing changes, I'll approve this solution.

Comment: No they are not user generated content, they are more like logo and themes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just using static images as part of of your theme, you are indeed correct in your suggestion that using an image field is overkill. I'd even go so far as to say it's entirely incorrect to use image fields for static theme content: fields aren't very portable and add way too much overhead to something that'll likely be a part of every page on the site.

Instead, handling static images is built directly into Drupal's core API and [theming layer](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) (so, no need for a separate module). What you'll to do is reference the images in your theme using [preprocess functions and the Drupal API](http://drupal.org/node/457740).

Let's assume you have a logo (`logo.png`) in the `images/` directory of your theme, and you want to display that logo on every page. In the [`page.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7) template file of your theme, you could do something like this:

```
<p><img src="/path/to/theme/images/logo.png" alt="My Site" class="logo nav-home" /></p>
```

But that's pretty brittle: what if the theme moves to another directory? What you want to do instead is create a variable such that you could do something like this:

```
<p><?php print $logo; ?></p>
```

To do that, you create a preprocess function to create a variable for use in your templates. In your theme's `template.php` file, create the following function (if it doesn't already exist):

```
// Replace MYTHEME with your theme's short name
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
}
```

Then, get the path to the logo using [`drupal_get_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7):

```
// Replace MYTHEME with your theme's short name
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME');

  $logo_path = $theme_path . '/images/logo.png';
}
```

Finally, render the path to the logo as an image using [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7):

```
// Replace MYTHEME with your theme's short name
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME');

  $logo_path = $theme_path . '/images/logo.png';

  // Prepare the information needed to theme an image
  // @see theme_image()
  $image = array(
    'path' => $logo_path,
    'alt' => t('My Site'), // t() makes a string translatable
    'attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('logo', 'nav-home'),
    ),
  );
  $variables['logo'] = theme('image', $image);
}
```

Now, `$logo` is available for use anywhere in your theme's `page.tpl.php`. Do the same process (get the path to the image, then assign the themed image to a variable) for any other static images you want to use as part of your theme.